# Why is the "url to track the job" of my mapreduce on aws not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop

I have launched a simple mapreduce job on a cluster on AWS. In the logs, one of the first lines says :

```
The url to track the job: http://ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_yyyyyyyyyyy_yyyy/
```

I go there, but I can't connect. I tried to go directly to

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20888/proxy/application_yyyyyyyyyyy_yyyy
```

but with no luck either. Any help? Thanks

Comment: This  is ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal a internal IP you cannot access internal IP using http.

Comment: so @error2007s ... how can I access it ?

Comment: Does this EC2 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal has a public IP address?

Comment: maybe. is there a place in the aws console to look for this? cc @error2007s

Comment: Yes go to instances section in Console search for ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal and in description you will Public DNS or Public Ip http://imgur.com/a/izch7

Comment: thanks, I found the public dns (zzz.zzz....) but `http://ec2-zzz-zzz-zzz-zzz.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:20888/proxy/application_yyyyyyyyy_yyyy/` couldn't connect

Comment: Do you have this port 20888 open in you security group

Comment: You absolutely can use the internal DNS address, as long as you're in the same VPC (or region for EC2-Classic).